# Kuka KR-C4 Documentation

Tags: software, industrial-robot, kuka

Is there an official documentation from Kuka that explains at a beginner level how to start programming Kuka Robots equipped with KR-C4 controllers?

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* ΦXocę 웃 Пepeúpa ツ, but I'm afraid that questions like this really aren't a good fit for a stack exchange site. We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](http://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*. Take a look at [ask] and [about] for more information on how stack exchange works. Also, the [*Robotics* question checklist](http://meta.robotics.stackexchange.com/q/1302/37) has good advice on how to write a good question. If you edit your question to fit our community guidelines we can reopen it for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Kuka KRC4 Controller can be programmed using the KRL language. [This](http://cncmanual.com/kuka-system-software-8-2-operating-programming-instructions/) official Kuka manual  gives a good introduction to both basics of hardware and software.

KRL is a high level programming language which runs on a mixed Windows-VxWorks environment.